# ckeditor 3.0 causes "unauthenticated content" when simply included on an HTTPS page

Tags: security, firefox, exception, ssl, ckeditor

When I include ckeditor aka fckeditor (version 3.0.1 revision 4391), which I downloaded from their site last week, into a page that is SSL encrypted, I get the Firefox broken lock icon and the warning "Warning: contains unauthenticated content". However, IE8 doesn't give this error at all. I checked the headers (Live HTTP headers), and everything is being included VIA SSL. Anyone have any solutions regarding this?

This happens by just including the script, like so
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/manager/settings.js"></script>

Comment: Sorry, the include is js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js, not js/manager/settings.js, I copied the wrong text!

Answer (score 2):

I also found the same problem on our secure portal. Only those web pages using the "ckeditor.js" is giving this warning.

Tried for some time searching through the ckeditor js files to find anywhere which uses http instead of https.

"plugins/flash/dialogs/flash.js" is having the embed from "http://macromedia blah blah...". Changing it to "https://macromedia .. blah blah..." did not solve it although our general flash embedded pages works fine with this workaround. :(

I will try to find out some more in the code... tonight.

If you find solution please put it here...

---

[http://dev.fckeditor.net/ticket/3905][1]

This will be fixed on 3.1.x onwards as it says.

trying to checkout a development tag.

---

Checked out CKEditor from a development branch under 3.1.x

This is great! the warning is gone.